# How to find the longest matching sublists in a list

Tags: list-manipulation, programming

Given a list of 2D points, i.e.

```
 {p1, p2, ..., pn}
```

the list may contain equal points, i.e. pi = pj. In this case it may also be true that a sublist of consecutive points has an equal somewhere in the list, i.e.:

```
 pi=pj and p(i+1)=p(j+1).
```

I am looking for the longest of such sublists in the list.

For example, in

```
 { {0,0}, {1,0}, {1,1}, {0,1}, {2,0}, {3,0}, {3,1}, {2,1}, {1,0}, {1,1}, {4,0}}
```

the sublist I am looking for is

```
{{1,0}, {1,1}}
```

has length 2 and occurs twice.

I am looking for an efficient way to ( functionally ) code this in Mathematica.

Question: **How to find the longest matching sublists in a list?**

Answers sofar failed on the following testcase, which I shall add for your convenience:L

```
 {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}, {2, 0}, {3, 0}, {3, 1}, {2, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {4, 0}, {0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}, {2, 0}, {3, 0}, {3, 1}, {2, 1}, {1, 0}, {2, 2}, {4, 0}};
```

with as longest matching sublist

```
 {{0, 0},{1, 0}, {1, 1},{0, 1},{2, 0},{3, 0},{3, 1},{2, 1},{1, 0}}
```

Comment: What about `{{3,0},{3,1}}`?

Comment: Appears only once.

Comment: But it is just as long as `{{1,0},{1,1}}`...

Comment: Ok, I mean {1,0}={1,0} and {1,1}={1,1} .

Comment: You should supply some more test cases to help eliminate ambiguity.

Comment: You want the longest sublist that appears at least twice or the sublist of length at least two that appears the most?

Comment: I wonder ... the accepted answer doesn't seem to work. Perhaps you want to revisit the accept checkmark.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is my solution, based on recursion and the use of the `LongestCommonSubsequence` built-in function. It assumes that the common subsequences can not overlap.

```
ClearAll[half]
half[lst_] /; EvenQ[Length[lst]] := Through[{Take, Drop}[lst, Length[lst]/2]];

ClearAll[pickLonger];
SetAttributes[pickLonger,Orderless];
pickLonger[fst_List,sec_List] /; Length[fst] >= Length[sec]:= fst;

ClearAll[$unique,lcomm];
    lcomm[lst_] /; OddQ[Length[lst]]:=
        lcomm[Append[lst,$unique]];
lcomm[lst_]:=
    With[{result=LongestCommonSubsequence @@ half[lst]},
        result/;result=!={}
    ];
lcomm[lst_]:=
    pickLonger @@ lcomm /@ half[lst]
```

What it does is to split a list in two halves and test for common subsequence. If it does not occur, `lcomm` applies itself recursively to the two halves of the list, and picks the largest result. If the list has odd number of elements, a spurious element is added at the end, so that the list can be evenly divided.

Examples:

```
test={{0,0},{1,0},{1,1},{0,1},{2,0},{3,0},{3,1},{2,1},{1,0},{1,1},{4,0}};
lcomm[test]

(* {{1, 0}, {1, 1}} *)
```

and

```
 ltest = {
    {0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}, {2, 0}, {3, 0}, {3, 1}, 
    {2, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {4, 0}, {0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, 
    {0, 1}, {2,0}, {3, 0}, {3, 1}, {2, 1}, {1, 0}, {2, 2}, {4, 0}
 };
 lcomm[ltest]

(* {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}, {2, 0}, {3, 0}, {3, 1}, {2, 1}, {1, 0}} *)
```

Comment: Okay, in `half` should `Length[lst]2` be `Length[lst]/2`?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks! Indeed. I was using my code formatter to post here, which has bugs for multiplication and, therefore,  division.  Another reason for me to fix those.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin: is there a working version of this elsewhere? Searched but came up empty.

Comment: @rasher Working version of what? The code above does work, after having been fixed.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin: Perhaps I misunderstand the op, but, e.g., `{{0, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}}` should return `{0,1},{1,0},{1,1}` as I understand the OP, code returns `{1,0},{1,1}`

Comment: @rasher Oh, I see. Apparently my logic wasn't correct. I will try to remember to revisit this over the weekend - unfortunately have no time right now.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin: Double-checking my results, it appears it also blows up if there are no common sublists. No worries, when I came across it and eyeballed it, I thought "this can't always work" and that was my first test case. Neat question, might take a swing at it using suffix-trees myself...

Comment: @rasher You are probably right in that there are problems with this solution. As I said, hopefully I will revisit it over the weekend. Thanks for pointing this out, b.t.w.

Comment: @rasher Actually, I remember that I had some doubts too, when writing this, but then probably discarded them too early.

Answer (score 6):

How about (assuming there is at least one list longer than 1 - else add a conditional to discard if result has length 1):

```
list/. {___, Longest[x___], ___, x___, ___} :> {x}
```

Note: is performance an issue for you?

Note2: as to @Rojo's comment above: this will return the longest subsequence that appears at least twice (and not the subsequence that appears most)

Answer (score 3):

If we set

```
li = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, ..., {1, 1}, {4, 0}} (*your list*)
```

then (**EDITED**)

```
preliminary = Last@
    SortBy[
       ReplaceList[li, {___, x__, Shortest[y__], x__, ___} :> {x}],
       Length
   ];
result = If[Length[preliminary] > 1, preliminary, {}]
```

returns
    {{1, 0}, {1, 1}}
and should solve also the other examples you provided.

The issue is that the match can occur in several ways, and I now explicitely select the longest among the matches.  Then, a result with a single element is discarded.

Does it sound ok now?

Comment: This list should return {} but fails on the solution you gave: {{Sqrt[3]/2, 1/2}, {0, 1}, {-(Sqrt[3]/2), 1/
  2}, {-(Sqrt[3]/2), -(1/2)}, {0, -1}, {Sqrt[3]/
  2, -(1/2)}, {-(Sqrt[3]/2), 1/2}, {0, 1}, {-(1/2), 
  1/2 (2 + Sqrt[3])}, {1/2 (-1 - Sqrt[3]), 
  1/2 (1 + Sqrt[3])}, {-(1/2), 1/2 (2 + Sqrt[3])}, {0, 1}, {1/2, 
  1/2 (2 + Sqrt[3])}, {1/2, 1/2 (2 + Sqrt[3])}, {0, 1}, {Sqrt[3]/2, 1/
  2}, {1/2 (1 + Sqrt[3]), 1/2 (1 + Sqrt[3])}, {1/2 (1 + Sqrt[3]), 
  1/2 (1 + Sqrt[3])}, {Sqrt[3]/2, 1/2}, {1/2 (2 + Sqrt[3]), 1/2}}

Comment: It was not clear to me that a single repeated element should not be returned. In this case, we can use: li /. {___, x__, Shortest[y__], x__, ___} :> 
  If[Length[{x}] > 1, {x}, {}]

Comment: Now it fails on this list: 
{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}, {2, 0}, {3, 0}, {3, 1}, {2, 1}, {1, 
   0}, {1, 1}, {4, 0}, {0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}, {2, 0}, {3, 
   0}, {3, 1}, {2, 1}, {1, 0}, {2, 1}, {4, 0}};

Comment: So far, so good, thanks

Answer (score 3):

I thought of patten matching, as user8074 did, but I don't think we need [`ReplaceList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ReplaceList.html) here.

I missed Pinguin Dirk's answer; this can be thought of as a variation of it.

I haven't tested this well but I think it should work:

```
longSS = Fold[Replace, #, {{___, Longest[x__], ___, x__, ___} :> {x}, {_} | # :> {}}] &
```

A test:

```
longSS /@ {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 5}, {1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3}}
```

> ```
> {{}, {1, 2}, {}, {1, 2, 3}}
> ```

This has poor computational complexity.  Leonid's approach appears to be much better once it is working.

Answer (score 3):

This is for pre-7 versions (that don't have `LongestCommonSubsequence`). It is not especially efficient, but seems faster than solutions that use some form of replacement. Also, if there are several equal-length longest-repeated-sublists then it will return all of them.

```
longsub[list_] := Block[{n = Floor[Length@list/2], r, u},
While[n > 0 && (r = Max[(u = Tally@Partition[list,n,1])[[All,2]]]) == 1, n--];
{n, r, Pick[u[[All,1]],u[[All,2]],r]}]

longsub[testcase]

(* {9, 2, {{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}, {2, 0}, {3, 0}, {3, 1}, {2, 1}, {1, 0}}}} *)
```

Comment: +1. I was too thinking along these lines, but then opted for the one I posted.

Answer (score 2):

I (embarrassingly) misunderstood this question when I first posted an answer. I post this with the following caveats about 'longest sequence':

1. In the following overlapping sequences will also be identified (this may not be the desired functionality), e.g. {1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3}->{1,2,3,1,2,3}. This could be accounted for.
2. More than one sequence could be the same longest length. Methods such as `Fold[Replace, #, {{___, Longest[x__], ___, 
    x__, ___} :> {x}, {_} | # :> {}}] &` will detect first identified. e.g

`longSS[{a, b, f, c, d, a, b, g, c, d}]` yields {a,b} but {c,d} is also an acceptable answer.

### Note also extra curly brackets in output relate to the issue of possible multiple maximal subsequences.

```
func[u_] :=
 Module[{v, tb, mx, mxm, ps, sb, pk, pks},
  v = Append[u, ToString[u[[-2]] u[[-1]]]];
  tb = Table[
    MapThread[Boole@SameQ[#1, #2] &, {v, RotateLeft[v, j]}], {j, 
     Length[v] - 1}];
  mx = (Max /@ Map[Total, Split /@ tb, {2}]);
  mxm = Max@mx;
  If[mxm <= 1, Return[{}]];
  ps = Position[mx, mxm];
  sb = Split /@ Extract[tb, ps];
  pk = Map[
    Function[x, Flatten[If[Total@# == Max@mx, #, 0. #] & /@ x]], sb];
  pks = Union@Map[Union@Partition[#, mxm] &, Pick[v, #, 1] & /@ pk];
  Flatten[pks, 1]
  ]
```

Testing cases:

```
test = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}, {2, 0}, {3, 0}, {3, 1}, {2, 
    1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {4, 0}, {0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}, {2, 
    0}, {3, 0}, {3, 1}, {2, 1}, {1, 0}, {2, 2}, {4, 0}};
```

`func[test]` yields:

```
{{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}, {2, 0}, {3, 0}, {3, 1}, {2, 1}, {1, 
   0}}}


func /@ {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 5}, {1, 2, 3, 
   1, 2, 3}}
```

yields:

```
{{}, {{1, 2}}, {}, {{1, 2, 3}}}
```

More than one maximal repeated subsequence:

```
func[{a, b, c, d, g, a, b, f, c, d}]
```

yields:

```
{{a, b}, {c, d}}
```

or

```
func[{a, b, c, f, g, h, a, b, c, x, f, g, h, y, f, g, h}]
```

yields:

```
{{a, b, c}, {f, g, h}}
```

The original test case:

```
func[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}, {2, 0}, {3, 0}, {3, 1}, {2, 
   1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {4, 0}}]
```

gives:

```
{{{1, 0}, {1, 1}}}
```

Excepting extra parentheses, test cases are handled. Overlap detection may not be a desired feature.

I post this, not as an ideal answer, but probably as a penance for misunderstanding question in first place. I am learning a lot looking at the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

My belated answer to this interesting question (I ran across it yesterday when it popped up as "related".) The right way to do this, IMHO, is via a suffix-tree (I'm certain I saw an MMA version of *Ukkonen's* O(N) version, can't find it and I'd rather not reinvent the wheel). However, I pondered another way while searching for the above algorithm, and was surprised at its speed.

I tested it against all the answers, following is it timed against the two that gave correct answers (mosty - one seemed to treat overlaps rather haphazardly, both did not return complete sets). The other three answers were not timed: two give incorrect results, one was unusably slow at more than a few dozens of pairs.

Note this is just a cobbled-up work-in-progress made during a cigar binge, so it's not heavily tested, but it appears to give correct results, etc. If there's interest I'll spruce it up, or perhaps implement a suffix-tree version.

Code:

```
lss[list_, overlaps_: False, minlen_: 2, maxlenarg_: Infinity] := 

 Module[{reso = {}, g, p, res, 
   maxlen = If[maxlenarg == Infinity, Ceiling[Length[list]/2], maxlenarg], 
   topdown},

  topdown = Boole[maxlen < minlen];
  Map[(p = Partition[list, #, 1];
     g = GatherBy[Range@Length@p, p[[#]] &];
     g = If[! overlaps, Pick[g, UnitStep[(Max[#] - Min[#]) & /@ g - #], 1], g];
     res = p[[#]] & /@ Flatten@Select[g, Length[#] > 1 &]; 
     If[(topdown == 0 && res == {}) || (topdown == 1 && res =!= {}), 
      Return[Gather[If[topdown == 1, Union@res, reso]], Module], 
      reso = Union@res]) &, Range[minlen, maxlen, 1 - 2 topdown]]]
```

Timings, by number of elements (pairs), generated with `RandomInteger[{0, 10}, {numEles, 2}]` (caveat: on cigar-time netbook, and switched to Log plot so lss could be seen):

[image]